# Redefinition of enumerator - Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem on a old iOS application (4.3 !!), and when I Run, Test, Archive, ... I have some errors. I have never had this kind of problem.

[image]

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can delete this code, `UIUserInterfaceIdiom` is already defined inside `UIDevice.h`.